# Suma de resultados

Tags: java

Compañeros buenas noches, quisiera su ayuda para poder obtener la suma del resultado de todas las varianzas guardadas en todos los numeros de actividades que se realicen, este es mi codigo.

float [] numeros =new float[10];
        System.out.println("Numero de Actividades ");
        int n= lector.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i

```
    System.out.println("Tiempo optimista: ");
    a=lector.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Tiempo mas probable: ");
    b=lector.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Tiempo pesimista: ");
    c=lector.nextFloat();
    prom = (a+4*b+c)/6;
    System.out.println("El tiempo probable es: " + prom);
    var = ((c-a)/6)*2;
    System.out.println("La varianza es de: " + var);
```

Comment: Por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución sería agregar una variable antes de recorrer el for que sea la sumatoria de las varianzas y dentro del for deberías sumar el valor que tiene + la varianza de momento.

**Solución**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, var = 0, prom = 0;

        // [AGREGADO] Se declara suma
        float suma = 0;

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Numero de Actividades ");

        int n = lector.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            System.out.println("Tiempo optimista: ");
            a = lector.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Tiempo mas probable: ");
            b = lector.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Tiempo pesimista: ");
            c = lector.nextFloat();
            prom = (a + 4 * b + c) / 6;
            System.out.println("El tiempo probable es: " + prom);
            var = ((c - a) / 6) * 2;
            System.out.println("La varianza es de: " + var);

            // [AGREGADO] Por cada varianza que se genere, se sumará su valor a suma.
            suma = suma + var;
        }

        // [AGREGADO] Se imprime la suma de varianzas
        System.out.println("La suma de las varianzas es: " + suma);

        lector.close();
    }

}
```

*Aclaración:* 
Al preguntar trata de escribir todo el código, no solo un fragmento. El código está cortado y no estoy seguro de si es lo que necesitas, por lo que solo me puedo basar en tu pedido sin fijarme el código

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda tu asesoría y ya quedo la suma. Y una disculpa, fue mi primer pregunta en esta plataforma. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Lo se, por eso eran las aclaraciones. Ahora solo queda que votes positivo en la respuesta y que valides que lo que te pasé es lo uqe te sirvió :D
Saludos!